# limitation on FusedLocationProviderApi Android

Tags: android

My app is using `android.location.LocationManager` to get network and gps locaitions.  Due to high battery consumption. I decided to switch to `FusedLocationProviderApi`. I'm worried about the impact on current users. Since this api requires google play service. is there any statistics on what percentage of android devices have google play service installed? is there any other things to consider that might cause current users unable to use the app after switch?

Comment: You also need to consider the version that your app requires.  Many devices are still being shipped with version 6.x, and if you require 7.x, you should add functionality to your app to prompt the user to upgrade.  Of course if the user opts to not upgrade, then your app will not be able to get geo-coordinates on that device.  This is something we ran into at my company recently, and we decided to ship with version 6.4 instead of 7.3 as we initially planned to.  However, most users will upgrade, since the first time they use Google Maps or access the Play Store they will need to upgrade.

Comment: is there any place to find statistics on the play store versions? or find out what is the minimal required version for an api class? I'm checking on the google api reference https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability but it doesn't tell me when is it added added to the api.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is able to access play store , the google play services are installed.

below is the play services description from play store

'Google Play services is used to update Google apps and apps from Google Play. This component provides core functionality like authentication to your Google services, synchronized contacts, access to all the latest user privacy settings, and higher quality, lower-powered location based services. Google Play services also enhances your app experience. It speeds up offline searches, provides more immersive maps, and improves gaming experiences. Apps may not work if you uninstall Google Play services.'

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97145/get-rid-of-google-play-services

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104842/is-it-safe-to-uninstall-google-play-services-app